# Should certain topics/tags create a wiki to summarize FAQs on those topics/tags?

Tags: feature-request, tag-wiki

I am constantly using stackoverflow as a great resource to begin any search for questions/solutions I am looking for.

As there are more and more questions/answers with the best answer bubbling to the top, wouldn't it make sense to have a wiki page to take these answers and add them to one common wiki page for this certain tag/topic?

I think this would add a great deal of benefit to the stackoverflow site.  It would not only become a place to search for a specific tag/topic, but also a quick reference manual.  Being a wiki, this could constantly be updated as better answers/solutions are found.

Just a thought.

Comment: @Jon: the text of the request describes something very different from the title.  He's also talking about a place the compiles the highest voted answers with a tag rather than a community edited page for the tag.

Comment: Sorry for not paying enough attention to the text. Too many things claiming my eyeballs tonight :(

Answer (score 1):

I actually find this request interesting, but the more I think about it the less it works in my head.

When I first thought about it, I was picturing a wiki page forming when a tag got popular enough that was displaying the top questions and such, but then I quickly realized that this is already being done for EVERY tag already just by the tag homepage.

Your part about taking answers and adding them to the common wiki page doesn't work IMHO because adding answers without the proper context of the question it is answering doesn't make a whole lot of sense. You just have a bunch of answers that aren't really answering anything anymore.

If this was something more along the lines of a FAQ page being generated where users could then post common practices as far as questions and answers are concerned, then MAYBE, but I find it to be so rare of a necessity that it doesn't make any real sense.

Nearly everything concerning a tag can be handled directly from the tag's own homepage already. I think this is more than sufficient for someone interested in finding out all the really popular information that has been squirreled away in that tag.

Answer (score 1):

Data Explorer to the rescue:
https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/104011/highest-voted-answers-by-tag?Tag=c%23

(Warning: it takes a few moments to run the query).

You can substitute in any tag you want.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the most frequently viewed or highest rated questions for a given tag might have a similar effect.